# Typical ormconfig.json file for Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, typeorm

I have been trying for hours. What should be the ormconfig.json file for Google Cloud SQL working with TypeORM? I managed to get it working with the IP of the DB locally (with mysql workbench and Google cloud proxy and whitelisting my ip) but I don't know what the connection details should be for app engine.

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "/cloudsql/[project:region:instance]",
  "port": "3306",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "xxxx",
  "database": "yyy",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": [
    "modules/**/*.entity.js"
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "mysql",
  "extra": {
    "socketPath": "/cloudsql/[project:region:instance]"
  },
  "username": "root",
  "password": "xxxx",
  "database": "yyy",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": [
    "modules/**/*.entity.js"
  ]
}
```

or anything else?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For those interested, here is the solution:

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "mysql",
  "extra": {
    "socketPath": "/cloudsql/[project:region:instance]"
  },
  "username": "root",
  "password": "xxxx",
  "database": "yyy",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": [
    "dist/**/*.entity.js"
  ]
}
```

Note that I also changed the `entities` path

Comment: How is `entities` path supposed to be correct? This way of connecting creates connection but doesn't create repositories. I tried `lib/entity/**/*.js` but without success.

Comment: It depends on the outDir option of your ```tsconfig.json```. The point is that once you transpile your, the production code of the entities is no longer at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't worked for me until I added the "cloud_sql" path also the the "host":

```
{
     "name": "default",
     "host": "/cloudsql/[project:region:instance]",
     "type": "mysql",
     "extra": {
       "socketPath": "/cloudsql/[project:region:instance]"
     },
     "username": "root",
     "password": "xxxx",
     "database": "yyy",
     "synchronize": true,
     "logging": false,
     "entities": [
         "dist/**/*.entity.js"
     ]
}
```