# Connect to Google Cloud MySQL instance from local running NodeJS / TypeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, typeorm

I am trying to connect to local GCloud MySQL instance from my local machine. I managed to connect to the instance from Workbench. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895612/typical-ormconfig-json-file-for-google-cloud-sql) it says to add a socketPath in extra when creating the config file. But since I'm trying to run this on local machine I tried changing that "/cloud/" path in many ways but didn't succeed.

Can someone please explain how I can connect to GCloud MySQL instance from a local NodeJS project that use TypeORM.

Answer (score 2):

As per the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) we can establish a connection to Cloud SQL from an application running outside of Google Cloud Platform in different ways. Now,  I went through the documentation and I found that you can use a Proxy if is for local test environment. I successfully reproduced this scenario and I did all the steps that the documentation said. According to my tests, there is no need to change the socket path.

Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an application locally and want to connect to a Cloud SQL instance, I would recommend the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test). It creates local entrypoint (Unix socket or TCP port, depending on what you tell it) that will authenticate and proxy your connections to your instance.